# Анимация пути перемещение карты на холсте HTML5 при прокрутке вниз страницы

Tags: javascript, html5, svg, анимация, canvas

Я новичок в `HTML5 CANVAS`. Когда я посетил этот [сайт](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/magazine/2016/05/yellowstone-national-parks-bears-video/) и этот [сайт](https://tympanus.net/Development/StorytellingMap/), я был удивлен фантастическими действиями, при прокручивании вниз. Карты опускаются вниз и  продолжают показывать информацию.

Я хочу использовать `Canvas` вместо чистого `SVG`. Если у меня есть SVG-файл карты с контуром (с помощью `<path>`), то как я могу достичь этого эффекта? (путь перемещения карты при прокрутке страницы)

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53587028/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы нарисовать путь SVG на `canvas`, вам нужно использовать `Path2D`. В следующем примере я использую диапазон анимации `stroke` для анимации  яблока. Вы можете использовать `scroll event`.

```js
// get the path's data
var svgPathApple= ap.getAttribute("d");
// get the path's length
let paths_length = ap.getTotalLength();

// initiate the canvas
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var cw = c.width = 500;
var ch = c.height = 500;
// create a new canvas path using Path2D
var theApple = new Path2D(svgPathApple);


ctx.lineDashOffset = -paths_length;
ctx.setLineDash([paths_length]);
ctx.stroke(theApple);
// use the input type range to change the lineDashOffset
ir.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  let v = ir.value;
  ctx.lineDashOffset = v;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.stroke(theApple);
})
```

```css
canvas,svg {
  border:1px solid
}

svg{display:none}
```

```html
<p><input id="ir" type="range" min="-909.682" value="-909.682" max="0" /></p>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<svg viewBox = "0 0 500 500">
  <path id="ap" d="M376.349,171.58 c0,0-37.276,22.484-36.094,60.946s31.438,61.577,42.012,63.313c4.127,0.678-24.314,57.988-42.039,72.189 s-36.067,17.159-64.47,5.917c-28.403-11.242-48.521,0.724-65.089,6.871s-36.687-0.361-63.905-39.415 s-57.396-129.585-15.976-173.964s87.574-26.627,100-20.71s34.32,5.325,59.172-5.917S363.922,153.237,376.349,171.58z" />
</svg>
```